# Combining ~ | and between in pandas filter

Tags: python, pandas

The idea here is to keep all values except those between 4900-4999 and 6000-6999. However, this code does not work at all. It seems to work if I break it up into two lines. Now searching for the correct syntax.

```
crsp = crsp[~(crsp['SICCD'].between(4900, 4999)) | ~(crsp['SICCD'].between(6000, 6999))]
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using `~` if you want to *keep* the values, it seems just `crsp[(crsp['SICCD'].between(4900, 4999)) | (crsp['SICCD'].between(6000, 6999))]` should be what you want (note you have a spurious `]` in your code)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that. I was using ~ as I do not want to keep values within those ranges, but all other values.

Comment: I think your problem is that you want to use `&` instead of `|`.

What you have written says keep everything.  You want to keep the rows that are not between (4900, 4999) AND not between (6000, 6999)

Comment: @r-learning-machine my bad, I missed the "except"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically correct, but you need to use `&`, not `|`, as one of the two conditions `crsp['SICCD'].between(4900, 4999))` and `crsp['SICCD'].between(6000, 6999)` will *always* be false (hence negated, one will *always* be true). For example:

```py
test = random.choices(range(4000,8000), k=20)
df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['Data'])
```

Sample data:

```
    Data
0   6113
1   4681
2   6891
3   4991
4   6576
5   5087
6   6111
7   5364
8   6658
9   4072
10  4327
11  5517
12  5421
13  6814
14  7099
15  6058
16  4404
17  6397
18  4851
19  6606
```

Now filter:

```py
df = df[~(df['Data'].between(4900,4999)) & ~(df['Data'].between(6000,6999))]
```

Output:

```
    Data
1   4681
5   5087
7   5364
9   4072
10  4327
11  5517
12  5421
14  7099
16  4404
18  4851
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by using a `np.where()`

```
test = np.arange(3000, 8000)
df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['Data'])
df['Check'] = np.where((df['Data'].between(4900, 4999)) | (df['Data'].between(6000, 6999)), True, False)
df.loc[df['Check'] == False]
```